# mysql database adding trailing 0 to decimal

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, gis, latitude-longitude

I have a db storing latitude and longitude.  I have the latitude column set to decimal 9,7 and longitude set to decimal 10,7.  It works fine when the latitude is 9 numbers long, problem is if the latitude is 8 numbers long it is adding a trailing 0 to the coordinates.  Is there a way in phpmyadmin to prevent this?  Or should I round the decimals with php before adding them to the db?

Comment: Is this a problem when using the db in php or just an aesthetic issue when viewing the data in phpmyadmin?

Comment: Problem when using the data, I am trying to match lat/lng and it won't match sometimes because of this placeholder 0 that is being added.

Comment: I'd cast the values to int (or use `intval()`) when retrieving the data from the db. However, I think php should do that by itself...how do you connect to mysql?

Comment: Ill just count with js and append a 0 if the length is less for this search.  thought I was doing something wrong but I think its just the way this works.  Thanks for the responses.

Comment: how ie where are you trying to match in the first place? in a mysql query, in php? in either it should be possible to cast the types accordingly which should likely solve the problem: in php cast both to float, in mysql CAST( your-val AS DECIMAL( 9, 7 ) )

Comment: it looks like my sql query had a syntax error, seems to be working find with or without the 0 now.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Latitude and longitude are inherently approximate values, especially those that are derived from GPS measurements. These are analog quantities, and imprecise ones at that, measured digitally.

You can't compare two of these values for equality and expect things to work correctly; approximate values don't work that way. They are inherently a bit fuzzy.

If you want to know if zip.long / zip.lat for example, are equal to long / lat, you need to use a SQL expression something like this.

```
 WHERE zip.long BETWEEN long - epsilon AND long + epsilon
   AND zip.lat  BETWEEN lat  - epsilon AND lat  + epsilon
```

If you're looking for 10 meter precision, epsilon should have the value 0.00001268 (1.268e-05).  We know this because a degree of latitude is sixty nautical miles, and it's easy to convert nautical miles to meters.

Your question about trailing zeros hints that you're using string comparison to match latitude and longitude. That is, with respect, even more deceptive than using numerical equality to compare numbers like that.

By the way, the `FLOAT` data type (32-bit IEEE 754 floating point) is plenty of precision for lat / long, unless you're a surveyor and know the difference between a Lambert and a UTM projection.